# What do these error messages tell me?

Tags: c++

I am trying to learn C++ so I apologize for this dumb question, if I just get this basic thing, a lot will become clear to me... I am following a guide to creating a keylogger meant to teach C++ while doing it. But the explanations are too weak and after writing the program exactly like instructed and try to debug I get:

> ```
> |=== Build: Debug in test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
> :\example\test\test\Timer.h|14|error: 'nullpointr' was not declared in this scope|
> :\example\test\test\Timer.h||In constructor 'Timer::Timer(const std::function<void()>&, const long unsigned int&, long int)':|
> :\example\test\test\Timer.h|44|error: no match for call to '(std::chrono::milliseconds {aka std::chrono::duration<long long int, std::ratio<1ll, 1000ll> >}) (std::chrono::milliseconds)'|
> :\example\test\test\Timer.h|45|error: expression cannot be used as a function|
> |=== Build failed: 3 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
> ```

I apologize for my first question not being well constructed, but I don't know where to start because of my total lack of experience. I am clueless what the error messages should tell me and how to understand the references etc. so I would really appreciate if someone could explain the different meanings of these few messages, like 'nullpointr' was not declared in this scope"... I tried finding the answers in already asked and answered, but I knew not how to find the explanation required for me to get it. I suppose you only need to see the code for this header since the other ones were error free...? Here it is (sorry for the ugly code, the code I copied had indented "{" and "}" but when pasting it showed most of them all the way to the left:

```
#ifndef TIMER_H
#define TIMER_H

#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

class Timer
{
std::thread Thread;
bool Alive = false;
long CallNumber = -1L;
long repeat_count = -1L;
std::chrono::milliseconds interval = std::chrono::milliseconds(0);
std::function<void(void)> funct = nullpointr;

void SleepAndRun()
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(interval);
    if(Alive)
        Function()();
}

void ThreadFunc()
{
    if (CallNumber == Infinite)
        while(Alive)
            SleepAndRun();
    else
        while(repeat_count--)
            SleepAndRun();
}

public:
static const long Infinite = -1L;

Timer(){}

Timer(const std::function<void(void)> &f) : funct (f) {}

Timer(const std::function<void(void)> &f,
      const unsigned long &i,
      const long repeat = Timer::Infinite) : funct (f)
                                            {
                                                interval(std::chrono::milliseconds(i)),
                                                CallNumber(repeat) {}
                                            }

 void Start(bool Async = true)
{
    if(IsAlive())
        return;
    Alive = true;
    repeat_count = CallNumber;
    if(Async)
        Thread = std::thread(ThreadFunc, this);
    else
        this->ThreadFunc();
}

void Stop()
{
    Alive = false;
    Thread.join();
}

void SetFunction(const std::function<void(void)> &f)
{
    funct = f;
}

bool IsAlive() const {return Alive;}

void RepeatCount(const long r)
{
    if(Alive)
        return;
    CallNumber = r;
}

long GetLeftCount() const {return repeat_count;}

long RepeatCount() const {return CallNumber;}

void SetInterval(const unsigned long &i)
{
    if(Alive)
        return;
    interval = std::chrono::milliseconds(i);
}

unsigned long Interval() const {return interval.count();}

const std::function<void(void)> &Function() const
{
    return funct;
}
};
#endif
```

If anyone can help me with this I would be very grateful, thanks.

Comment: It's `nullptr`, not `nullpointr` :)

Comment: If you post here, make sure your code is compilable - particularly, #include all the headers that will make it so.

Comment: Are you compiling using `g++` or `gcc`?  Prefer to use `g++` when you are using the C++ language.

Answer (score 3):

The first error is telling you that `nullpointr` is not defined. You are probably meaning to use `nullptr`, which is part of the C++ language.

The other two errors deal with your third constructor. It appears you have placed two of your member initializers in the constructor, and done them incorrectly at that.

```
Timer(const std::function<void(void)> &f,
      const unsigned long &i,
      const long repeat = Timer::Infinite) : funct (f)
                                            {
                                                interval(std::chrono::milliseconds(i)),
                                                CallNumber(repeat) {}
                                            }
```

What you probably want is:

```
Timer(const std::function<void(void)> &f,
      const unsigned long &i,
      const long repeat = Timer::Infinite) : funct (f),interval(i), CallNumber(repeat) 
{}
```